# How to redirect after session has expired using an interceptor Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
            *@Override
            public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
                        throws Exception {

                    System.out.println("INTERCEPTING---");
                    if(request !=null && request.getParameter("email")!=null){

                        System.out.println("session is NOT null------");
                        session = request.getSession();
                        session.setAttribute("user", request.getParameter("email"));

                    }else{

                        try{

                            if (session==null){

                                System.out.println("session lost");

                            }

                        }catch(IllegalStateException exception){

                            System.out.println("session expired");
                            "redirect:http://localhost:8080/web/authservice/fail";
```

/*this is the redirection that i used, and i tried model and view as well but yet it does not work*/
                            }

```
                    }

                    return true;
                }
    /*in the above method how should I redirect. Its not redirecting...............
Im unable to redirect the after the session expired it gives me a response commit exception. I ve been trying for hours no solution
```

Please provide a suitable solution   */

Comment: where have you written your redirection code ?

Comment: i tried to redirect using "redirect:" inside the session expired catch block

Comment: Did you try throwing with  `ModelAndView(redirectView, "error", "sessionTimeout);`

Comment: yes not working either, i almost tried everything in stack

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense: session is not declared, you're testing the presence of a *request* parameter to decide if the *session* has expired, and of course, you have no redirection code at all.

Comment: can you please update your code snippet to have us a better understanding of your context.

Answer (score 0):

Use a servlet filter instead, (place it according to you intercepet requirement in your web.xml).

```
public class CustomRequestFilter implements Filter {
      WebApplicationContext springContext;
      @Override
      public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(filterConfig.getServletContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException, LicenseException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        if (XXX) {
            //forward or redirect as per requirement
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/errors/SystemError.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```